# Please Explain The Flow of This Algorithm and How does it work?(Knuth Topological Sorting)

Tags: algorithm

Given a relation ~ on {1....n} with the property that x~y implies x < y, this algorithm generates all permutations a[1]....a[n] and their inverses a'[1].....a'[n] with the property that a'[j] < a'[k] whenever j~k. We assume for convenience that a[0] = 0 and that 0~k for 1<=k<=n.

V1. [Initialize.] Set a[j] <- j and a'[j] <- j for 0<=j<=n.

V2. [Visit.] Visit the permutation a[1]...a[n] and its inverse a'[1]...a'[n]. Then set k <- n.

V3. [Can k move left?]Set j <- a'[k] and l <- a[j-1]. If l~k, go to V5.

V4. [Yes, move it.] Set a[j-1] <- k, a[j] <- l, a'[k] <- j-1, and a'[l] <- j. Go to V2.

V5. [No, put k back.] While j < k, set l <- a[j+1], a[j] <- l, a'[l] <- j, and j <- j +1.
    Then set a[k] <-a'[k] <-k. Decrease k by 1 and return to V3 if k > 0.

Already tried implementing it but got confused with the flow. Kindly explain the flow of this algorithm and how it works based on precedence constraints such as 1~2 for say {1,2,3}.

Comment: Perhaps [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knuth, bless him, is an unreconstructed assembly language programmer. Here's a rendering of this algorithm into tested, goto-less Python. `precedes` is the relation `~`.

```
from itertools import permutations


def topological_orders(n, precedes):
    a = list(range(n + 1))
    ai = a[:]
    while True:
        yield tuple(a[1:])
        k = n
        while True:
            j = ai[k]
            l = a[j - 1]
            if not precedes(l, k):
                a[j - 1] = k
                a[j] = l
                ai[k] = j - 1
                ai[l] = j
                break
            while j < k:
                l = a[j + 1]
                a[j] = l
                ai[l] = j
                j += 1
            a[k] = ai[k] = k
            k -= 1
            if not k > 0:
                return


def test(n, precedes):
    fast_orders = set()
    for order in topological_orders(n, precedes):
        print(order)
        fast_orders.add(order)
    slow_orders = set()
    for order in permutations(range(n + 1)):
        if not any(precedes(order[i], order[j]) for i in range(n + 1) for j in range(i)):
            slow_orders.add(order[1:])
    assert fast_orders == slow_orders


if __name__ == '__main__':
    def divides(a, b):
        return a < b and (a == 0 or b % a == 0)

    test(6, divides)
```

On your input, we start with

```
0123.
```

Visit `123` and move `3` to the left.

```
0132
```

Visit `132` and move `3` to the left.

```
0312
```

Visit `312`. We can't move `3` because `0 ~ 3`. Move it all the way to the right and try to move `2`.

```
0123
```

We can't move `2` because `1 ~ 2`. Try to move `1`. We can't move `1` because `0 ~ 1`. Try to move `0` -- oops, we're done.

Comment: Could you explain what you have done in test, precedes and divides. I have never seen python code. Sorry!

Comment: @SurajSangani The condition `j ~ k` in the pseudocode is equivalent to `precedes(j, k)` in the Python. `precedes` is an argument that is callable. `divides` is just an example relation for testing purposes and has nothing to do with the operation of `topological_orders`.

Comment: The code never enters the while loop because j=k=n and does not enter the if loop too because l is always smaller than k. If I am wrong please correct me. Thanks!

Comment: @SurajSangani I included my test case and eye-balled it to make sure that it was sane. `l` may be smaller than `k`, but it is not always the case that `l ~ k`.